# Programatically added HTML Button - OnServerClick doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

> Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Case</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testdiv" runat="server"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testdiv.InnerHtml = "<input type=\"button\" runat=\"server\" OnServerClick=\"Test_Click\"/>";
    }

    protected void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testdiv.InnerHtml = "REGISTERED CLICK!";
    }
}
```

---

I want `Test_Click` to be run on the server when the button is clicked, but it doesn't.

I tried putting it in a server side form, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried OnClick instead of OnServerClick?

Comment: OnClick is client-side. I need it server-side.

Comment: By adding runtat="server" you have already made the button a server side button, so OnClick should be calling server-side methods.

Comment: Your adding it with html text.. try to create the object directly on the server, if possible, create your whole table on server side

Comment: The other option is to call the server side method from javascript. Look at http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-server-side-function-from-JavaScript-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this way,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = new Button {ID = "Button1", Text = "Test Button"};
    button.Click += button_Click;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testdiv.InnerHtml = "Button1 is clicked";
}
```

Comment: I can't do that. I'm creating a `<table>` in a deferred way.

Comment: I doesn't matter how you create your table, just move created control  in javascript to wherever you need it to be.

Comment: That's not very elegant.

Comment: I didn't know code was for miss universe, If you want better solution share your table generating part so we can see your "elegant" code.

Comment: and why this is string generated html rather than a gridview?

Comment: @IvanRubinson i've been through that too, i once did just like you with string html inside a div. It only caused problems and confusion until i did just like Mert, there is no getting away from it, you HAVE to create objects, even though your code migth work, it's going to be much simpler once you learn to do it this way